# Installing scipy for windows python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, package

So I need to install a bunch of packages, including scipy. I've installed a couple using pip, but when I say "pip install scipy", it fails. Why is this? And how do I correctly install it? Thanks.

EDIT: i say "pip install scipy". Doesn't work.

It fails to build scipy and throws the following error:

Cleaning up...
Command /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zl/7698ng4d4nxd49q1845jd9340000gn/T/pip-eO8gua-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/bin/../include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /Users/administrator/dev/KaggleAux/env/build/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/administrator/.pip/pip.log

Comment: What is the error message? You should post it.

Comment: It is `pip install scipy` and not `scipi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the relevant scipy package from this link: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

cp indicates the python version you have

do pip install wheel

then go to the folder where you downloaded the package and do 
pip install filename.whl

hopefully this should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.